# Alberta's winter is pretty mild

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> Republic of some merit, I'm the world's number one.
>   I'm colder than Alberta, as to snow I have a ton.
>   I'm larger than some countries, such as Nauru and Algeria.
>   Yet in a sense I'm smaller than Mauritius or Liberia.

What am I?

Comment: I really want to say rot13(Terraynaq. Vg svgf fb znal pyhrf.  Ohg vg vf fznyyre guna Nytrevn.)

Comment: @SteveV Yeah, that almost fits!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> The Sakha Republic in Russia

Republic of some merit, I'm the world's number one.

> Sakha Republic.
>  It is the largest subnational governing body by area in the world

I'm colder than Alberta, as to snow I have a ton.

> Sakha Republic is known for being cold; the Verkhoyansk Range is considered the coldest area in the Northern Hemisphere

I'm larger than some countries, such as Nauru and Algeria.

> The Sakha Republic is 3,083,523 square kilometers (1,190,555 sq mi), larger than both Nauru 21 sq km (8.1 sq mi) and Algeria 2,381,741 sq km (919,595 sq miles).

Yet in a sense I'm smaller than Mauritius or Liberia.

> The population of The Sakha Republic is 958,528, less than Mauritius (1,264,887) and Liberia (4,382,387).

Comment: This is correct. Well done!